# extract integer from an array in a certain interval

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I would like to extract the number from an array at a certain interval. The array is of size (1,20). I want to print the number from this array at an interval of 4. I am trying to print all the 4th numbers from 0 to 20 from the array. But I suspect my code Is not printing the right 4th number in the range 0 to 20. I am trying to extract the column numbers from `stimnumber` here. `stimnumber` has a shape (1,20)

If

```
stimnuber = [[1,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,0,0,0,0]]
```

I want to print all the numbers 1, 4, 8, 9 and 0.

```
j = 0
for j in range(stimnumber.shape[1]):
    while j < 5:
        stimnum = stimnumber[:,j::20]
        print(stimnum[:,j])
        j += 20
```

Comment: For a question like this, you should consider making a small example that others can reproduce. You don't need 216576 elements to explain this problem. Ask the question with a  specific array of say 20 elements and perhaps taking every 7th. Then you can show *exactly* what result you want. As is this question is unclear — what shape is results supposed to be? Are you always starting with something with a single nested list? etc.

Comment: I tried to edit some parts of it now. Yes, I am using a nested loop here.Thanks

Comment: It seems like you could flatten it and take a slice: `stimnuber.flatten()[::4]`

Comment: Lists don't have a `shape` attribute and don't support extended indexing. Is it actually a Numpy array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate with a step of 4

```
stimnumber =[[1,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,0,0,0,0]]
for i in range(0,len(stimnumber[0]),4):
  print(stimnumber[0][i])
```

Or as pointed by wjandrea if you are familiar with array slicing (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-comprehension-and-slicing/) you can try:

```
stimnumber =[[1,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,0,0,0,0]]
for i in stimnumber[0][::4]: print(i)
```

basically it means [start, stop, step] for the array locations

Comment: It's simpler to use slicing: `for i in stimnumber[0][::4]: print(i)`

Comment: Good point! I just updated the answer to include slicing